# Total Variation of a complex measure as an integral

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

Let $(\Omega,F,\mu)$ be a measure space and $v:\Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ be a complex measure. Suppose that
$$
v(A)=\int_{A}f d \mu \;\;\; \forall A\in F
$$
for some $\mathbb{C}$-valued $f\in L^{1}(\mu)$, show then that
$$
|v|(A)=\int_{A} |f| d\mu \;\;\; \forall A \in F.
$$
Here
$$
|v|(A)=sup\{ \sum_{i=1}^{n} |v(A_{i})| : A_{1},...,A_{n} \; \text{measureable partion of}\;A \}
$$
i.e. the total variation of $v$.

I know how to prove this for $\mathbb{R}$-valued $f$ by considering positive and negative parts. My issue is that I'm not sure how to upgrade this prove for $\mathbb{C}$-valued $f$. I suspect that I want to consider real and imaginary parts of $f$ but I'm not sure how specificlally.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a theorem in Rudin's RCA. See"Consequences of Radon Nikodym Theorem".

Comment: Found it! Thank you so much @Kavi Rama Murthy!